# Python avoid nested for loops

Tags: python-3.x

I have this block of code where I am using nested for loops

```
res1 = EC2_CLIENT.describe_instances(
            InstanceIds=[ec2_id,
            ],
        )['Reservations']
        
        print (res1)
        
        for r in res1:
            inst = r['Instances']
            for i in inst:
                ni = i['NetworkInterfaces']
                for n in ni:
                    g = n['Groups']
                    for g1 in g:
                        groupId = g1['GroupId']`
```

Is there a way I can simplify this block of code to retrieve groupId?

Comment: Looks like `res1[0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Groups'][0]['GroupId']` would do it.  This might produce different results if any of those lists have more than one item in them - your code chooses the last one, mine only looks at the first.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks that helps. But what if there are more items in the list? How can I work around that case?

Comment: Well, what behavior do you want it to have when there are multiple items in the lists?